# Aggregate various feeds and display them as blog entries?

Tags: drupal-6, blogs, rss

Newbie question on Drupal. I want to aggregate various rss feeds from various websites and display them in the main site page as blog entries. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use [Aggregator](http://drupal.org/node/289) module for your requirement. Its simple to configure and coming as core optional module in Drupal 6. Enable it and you'll get an admin settings as 'Feed Aggregator' in content management then use views or your module to generate page/block display

[video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uVRkvBFMmE)

Take a look my feed aggregator screenshot
[image]